# Image width and height validation in java script - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Trying to validate upload file height and width of an image from Javascript. Return false isn't working.

**Javascript Code:**

```
function Upload() {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("userfile");
    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.png|.gif)$");
    if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof(fileUpload.files) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = e.target.result;
                image.onload = function() {
                    var height = this.height;
                    var width = this.width;
                    if (height < 227 || width < 300) {
                        alert("Height and Width should be above 227px by 300px.");
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        alert("Uploaded image has valid Height and Width.");
                        return true;
                    }
                };
            }
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please select a valid Image file.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<form name="add_projects" id="add_projects"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Project Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="project_name" id="project_name" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->project_name;}?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->id;}?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Project Sub Category Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="project_sub_name" id="project_sub_name" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->project_sub_name;}?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tags</label>
                <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->tags;}?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Poject Description</label>
                <textarea id="editor1" name="project_description" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="80"><?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->project_description;}?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Current Image</label><br>
                <?php if(!empty($project) && $project->image !=""){?>
                    <img height="227" width="450" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/projects/<?=$project->image?>">
                <?php }else{ echo "No Image Selected";} ?>
            </div>
        </div>                      
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>New Image </label>
                <div id="preview" style="width:100%"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Image </label>
                <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
                <input type="hidden" name="old_file" value="<?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->image;}?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if(!empty($project)){ echo $project->id;}?>">
                <span class="error">(Image should be more then 300px in width and 227px in height or above)</span>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" onclick="return Upload();" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form gets submitted and does not stop submitting form, even when the image height and width is below specified pixels..

Where am i getting this wrong?

I am also using Jquery Validation for the form (jquery.validate.min.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code. The way you're trying to check the file extension is not working. Trying to return from inside a nested function will never work. You've got jQuery at your disposal, but don't use it. Obviously its better to use vanilla javascript whenever possible, but you're just making a big mess. I put together a little example of some working code, and tried to keep it as minimal as possible. It checks file size, type, and because you need it width and height.

You can notice that there are two validations going on. Once on file input change, and once on form submit. This is just to show you that it can be done. This example isn't necessarily complete, but should get you going. I tested it. It should be pretty easy to follow what's going on.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Get Image Size</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/whatever.php">
            <input id="file_input" type="file" name="userfile" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes">
        </form>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($){
                // Local namespace
                var namespace = {

                    /* 
                     * Check file for type and size on submission.
                     * It is assumed that the file is previously determined to exist.
                     *
                     * @param  file element  like $(<file_input>).files[0]
                     * @param  int  like 2000000 for 2MB
                     * @param  string like "application/pdf|image/jpeg"
                     * @param  int like 227 for min pixel height 227
                     * @param  int like 300 for min pixel width 300
                     */
                    validate_file_upload: function( file, max_file_size, allowed_types, min_img_height, min_img_width ){
                        if( ! 'size' in file || ! 'type' in file )
                            return false;
                        if( file.size > max_file_size )
                            return false;
                        if( file.type != '' && allowed_types.indexOf( file.type ) == -1 )
                            return false;
                        var url = URL.createObjectURL( file );
                        var img = new Image;
                        var error = false;
                        img.onload = function(){
                            if( img.height < min_img_height || img.width < min_img_width ){
                                error = true;
                            }
                        };
                        img.src = url;
                        if( error )
                            return false;
                        return true;
                    },

                    /* 
                     * Instant validation of file input on field change.
                     * 
                     * @param  file element  like $(<file_input>).files[0]
                     * @param  int  like 2000000 for 2MB
                     * @param  string like "application/pdf|image/jpeg"
                     * @param  int like 40000000 for 40MB
                     * @param  int like 227 for min pixel height 227
                     * @param  int like 300 for min pixel width 300
                     */
                    validate_file_input_on_change: function( file, max_bytes, allowed_mimes, post_max_size, min_img_height, min_img_width ){
                        var error = false;
                        /* Is the file even a file? */
                        if( ! 'size' in file || ! 'type' in file )
                        {
                            error = true;
                            alert('File not able to be validated.');
                        }
                        /* Is filesize too large? */
                        else if(file.size > max_bytes){
                            error = true;
                            var readableSize = this._humanFileSize(file.size, true);
                            alert('File size of ~' + readableSize + ' too large to upload.');
                        }
                        /* Else filesize is not too large */
                        else{
                            /* Is mime type allowed? */
                            if( file.type != '' && allowed_mimes.indexOf(file.type) == -1 ){
                                error = true;
                                alert('Mime type ' + file.type + ' not uploadable.');
                            }
                            /* Else mime type was allowed */
                            else{
                                var fields_total = 0;
                                $('input[type="file"]').each(function(i,el){
                                    if( el.files[0] != undefined )
                                        fields_total += el.files[0].size;
                                });
                                /* Is total combined filesize meet server expectations */
                                if( fields_total > post_max_size ){
                                    error = true;
                                    var combinedTotal = this._humanFileSize(fields_total, true);
                                    var postMax = this._humanFileSize(post_max_size, true);
                                    alert('Combined filesize total of ' + combinedTotal + ' exceeds the server limitation of ' + postMax + '.\n\nPlease reduce the number of uploads.' );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        /* Only check image dimensions if there is no existing error */
                        if( ! error ){
                            var url = URL.createObjectURL( file );
                            var img = new Image;
                            img.onload = function(){
                                if( img.height < min_img_height || img.width < min_img_width ){
                                    error = true;
                                    alert('Image height and/or width not large enough.');
                                }
                            };
                            img.src = url;
                        }
                        return ! error;
                    },

                    /* 
                     * Convert filesize in bytes to human readable MBs.
                     * Used by funcs.validate_file_input_on_change().
                     *
                     * @param  int  filesize in bytes, provided by File API
                     * @param  bool  is size vs size on disk
                     */
                    _humanFileSize: function(bytes, si) {
                        var thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;
                        if( Math.abs(bytes) < thresh )
                            return bytes + ' B';
                        var units = si
                            ? ['kB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB']
                            : ['KiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB','EiB','ZiB','YiB'];
                        var u = -1;
                        do {
                            bytes /= thresh;
                            ++u;
                        } while( Math.abs(bytes) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1 );
                        return bytes.toFixed(1) + units[u];
                    }

                // End local namespace
                };

                window.funcs = ( window.funcs ) 
                    ? $.extend( window.funcs, namespace ) 
                    : namespace;

            })(this.jQuery);

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#file_input').on('change', function(){
                    var file = this.files[0];
                    // Check filesize and file type
                    var status = funcs.validate_file_input_on_change( 
                        file, 
                        // Max bytes
                        200000,
                        // Allowed mimes
                        'image/jpeg|image/png|image/gif', 
                        // Max post bytes
                        40000000, 
                        // Min height
                        227, 
                        // Min width
                        300 
                    );
                });

                $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
                    var file = $('#file_input')[0].files[0];
                    if( funcs.validate_file_upload(
                        file, 
                        // Max bytes
                        200000,
                        // Allowed mimes
                        'image/jpeg|image/png|image/gif', 
                        // Min height
                        227, 
                        // Min width
                        300
                    )){
                        return true;
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```